# When to include services inside providers?

Tags: angular, service

I had just finished a small Angular 2 project and on comparing my work with the model answer code I noticed that when I looked at the providers in `app.module.ts` file the tutor had included only one of the two services created.

`users.service.ts`

```
    import { Component, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CounterService } from './counter.service';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
    activeUsers = ['Max', 'Anna'];
    inactiveUsers = ['Chris', 'Manu'];

    constructor(private counterService: CounterService) {}

setToActive(id: number) {
    this.activeUsers.push(this.inactiveUsers[id]);
    this.inactiveUsers.splice(id, 1);
    this.counterService.incrementInactiveToActive();
}

setToInactive(id: number) {
    this.inactiveUsers.push(this.activeUsers[id]);
    this.activeUsers.splice(id, 1);
    this.counterService.incrementActiveToInactive();
    }
 }
```

`counter.service.ts` (Used inside the users service via `@Injectable`)

```
export class CounterService {
activeToInactiveCounter = 0;
inactiveToActiveCounter = 0;

incrementActiveToInactive() {
    this.activeToInactiveCounter++;
    console.log('Active to Inactive Count:' + this.activeToInactiveCounter);
     }
  incrementInactiveToActive() {
  this.inactiveToActiveCounter++;
  console.log('Inactive to Active Count:' + this.inactiveToActiveCounter);
    }
}
```

Now looking inside the `app.module.ts` file he includes the `counter.service.ts` service but not the `user.service.ts` service?

`app.module.ts`

```
providers: [CounterService]
```

Can someone explain to me why he has not included both? Many thanks.

*EDIT* - `app.component.ts` for reference:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from './users.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [UserService]
})
 export class AppComponent {
}
```

Comment: Where does `UserService` get injected?

Comment: That's another weird thing, I only see `@Injectable()` inside of `users.service.ts` which is being used to facilitate the second service..

Comment: So `UserService` isn't injected into any components?

Comment: He might have registered the service provider in the providers property of component rather than of module

Comment: He may include `counter.service` in `app.module` because he wants it to be a global singleton service for your app and provided `user.service` in a different module or a component directly.

Comment: @ExplosionPills No, the only occurrence of `@Injectable' is inside of the `users.service.ts` file.. The only place UserService is referenced is when it's imported inside of the `app.component.ts` file.

Comment: Can you show us `app.component.ts` as well? At least where it injects user service?

Comment: Amended @ExplosionPills

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject providers into other providers, components, and modules. When you inject a provider at a particular level it gets created at that level, so a provider injected into a module is created once for the whole module. If it's injected in the component it's created once per component.

In this case, you probably only use the app component one time so ultimately the `UserService` only gets created once anyway, but if you used multiple `AppComponent` in your app, each one would have its own user service. However, they would all share the one `CounterService` since that gets injected at the module level.